# Virtual host Object not found

Tags: apache, ubuntu, xampp, virtualhost

Everytime I try to access `https://sub.myproject.test/` this message pops up:

*Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
sub.myproject.test
Apache/2.4.38 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2q PHP/7.2.15 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3*

On `httpd-vhosts.conf` I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/mnt/data/myproject/sub.myproject.com/public_html"
    ServerName sub.myproject.test
    ServerAlias www.sub.myproject.test
    <Directory  "/mnt/data/myproject/sub.myproject.com/public_html/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and on `httpd-ssl.conf` I have:

```
# catalog config
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/mnt/data/myproject/sub.myproject.com/public_html"
    ServerName sub.myproject.test:443
    ServerAlias www.sub.myproject.test:443
    ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/logs/error_log"
    TransferLog "/opt/lampp/logs/access_log"
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "/opt/lampp/etc/ssl.crt/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/lampp/etc/ssl.key/server.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "/mnt/data/myproject/sub.myproject.com/public_html/">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +FakeBasicAuth

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
             nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
             downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog "/opt/lampp/logs/ssl_request_log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

And of course in `/mnt/data/myproject` path I have the `sub.myproject.com` folder

If you could help me fix this, it'd be very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VirtualHost is ok (*except you do not need to put :443 in ServerName and ServerAlias directives*), but you never tell Apache which page to display by default, when not specified in the request.

Define `DirectoryIndex` in each VirtualHost.

Ex: `DirectoryIndex index.html`
When the request is https://example.com/ 
,hence nothing after the domain name, Apache will display index.html, from the `DocumentRoot` directory.

---

Unrelated to your question, you should put `ServerTokens Prod` and `ServerSignature Off` in your configuration, your error message is displaying way to much information.